# Integrate hibernate ORM with Couchbase

Tags: hibernate, couchbase, hibernate-ogm

I have been working on a legacy project which involves spring,hibernate and mariadb. Now there is a requirement where I need to migrate from mariadb to couchbase as well. I am assuming that there should not be significant level of code changes. I have tried looking on the internet to get some help in integrating hibernate orm with couchbase but no luck. Somehow I found that there are some paid versions that can handle such integration(hibernate-ogm). But i am not sure how can I do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is not a Hibernate OGM dialect for Couchbase, we only have one for CouchDB. It's experimental and you can find the source code on GitHub: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-ogm-couchdb

If you need help with it don't hesitate to ask for it on the [Hibernate OGM forum](https://discourse.hibernate.org/c/hibernate-ogm) or on the [other channels](http://hibernate.org/community/).

By the way, everything is free and open source. You don't have to pay.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I will surely look in to it. However if my requirement is stringent and would want to continue using couchbase given the fact that my application is based out of hibernate, then could you let me know what all strategies could I adopt....

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/) is not a paid version of Hibernate ORM, it's free and open-source, you can get it from Sourceforge or from Maven Central: http://hibernate.org/ogm/releases/5.1/#get-it

A getting started guide is available [here](http://hibernate.org/ogm/documentation/getting-started/).

Comment: Hello thanks for the information let me check it for

Comment: I did found the hibernate-ogm-couchdb jar, but i am not sure how would I be able to find the database drivers to connect to the couchbase. Please advise

Comment: You should check the documentation, this section in particular : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#ogm-couchdb